# Need More Information About KDE Job Notification

Tags: debian, security, kde

I installed Debian 7.2 on a new laptop a couple of days ago, and now I'm getting a strange job notification every once in a while. It just says the following:

```
Source: https://some.important.web.site.com/
```

(The web site is a medical one, so I'd rather not share the real URL.)

It seems unlikely, but it looks like some process on my newly-installed Linux machine is trying to talk to a web site that I haven't used in years for some reason. My fear is that I have some malicious code on my machine that is either trying to steal some of my money or DDOS someone.

Is there any log file I can look at to get more information about what is being executed? I would try `tcpdump`, but I can't see what is being sent back and forth since this is using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Change the [notification (knotify) settings](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-runtime/kcontrol/kcmnotify/) to include more info. I would pick logging to a file, so you don't miss out on them and use the placeholders mentioned under text-to-speech if the logged messages are not verbose enough by itself.

Once you get some notifications, you will be able to see which process sent them. Finding out why will be much easier after that.